# creating a dictionary from a text file and getting values from using key as input

Tags: python, dictionary, input, key

I am trying to create a dictionary from an existing text file but this should be done automatically
so for example I have this text file

```
0 1
0 3
1 2
```

now I want to create this dictionary

```
a={
"0": "1","3"
"1": "0","2"}
```

which way should I follow to create this dictionary so when I add an input that is going to ask for a value that one is going to be the key and display the values?

I tried something with creating a list of all the keys and then adding the values from the text file but it only gives one value that is linked so for example it displays only

```
"0": "1"
```

and not

```
"0": "1","3"
```

Comment: you can not have such a dict value `"0": "1","3"
` , perhaps you meant `"0": ["1","3"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list)
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        a[key].append(value)
print(a)
```

Comment: THere's no need to strip before splitting, since it ignores trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Use `setdefault()` to initialize each key to an empty list and append the value from that row.

```
a = {}

for line in file:
    key, value = line.split()
    a.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(a)
```